# file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile

[image]

when I'm running docker build.
then I shows this error can anyone please help me to fix that error

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base 
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 80 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build 
WORKDIR /src 
COPY ["examroom.itembanking-main.csproj", "./"] 
RUN dotnet restore "examroom.itembanking-main.csproj" 
COPY . . 
WORKDIR "/src/." 
RUN dotnet build "examroom.itembanking-main.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build 

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "examroom.itembanking-main.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish 

FROM base AS final 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=publish /app/publish . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "examroom.itembanking-main.dll"]
```

Comment: The file doesn't exist to copy. Where is that file?

Comment: **/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md                  I have added this in .dockerinore

Comment: That's not the file I'm asking about. I'd tell you which one, but I can't copy and paste from a picture. Please post the code as formatted text rather than a picture.

Comment: @Sunaina the build fails on `COPY["examroom.itembanking-main.csproj", "./"]` , but there is no file `examroom.itembanking-main.csproj` in the current directory.

Comment: @s3vt but my file path is ok